# how definition constant via prototype?

Tags: javascript

please help solve the problem.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeaaNj?editors=001)

i make script:

```
Board = function(width, height, background){ 
    this.width = width; 
    this.height = height;   
    this.background = background;   

    this.Create();
}

Board.prototype.Create = function(){
    var board = $('<div class="board" id="board"></div>').css({
        width: this.width + 'px',
        height: this.height + 'px',
        background: this.background
    });

    $('#game').append(board);
}


Tank = function(id){ 
  this.x_coord = helper.randomIntFromZero(481);
  this.y_coord = helper.randomIntFromZero(481);
  this.id = id; 
  this.arrow; 
  this.direction;
  this.DIRECTION = ['up', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];

  this.Create();
}

Tank.prototype.Create = function(){
  this.direction = this.DIRECTION[helper.randomIntFromZero(4)];

  var tank = $('<div class="tank" id="' + this.id + '"></div>').css({
    left: this.x_coord + 'px',
    top: this.y_coord + 'px'
  });

  $('#board').append(tank);
}

Tank.prototype.checkArrowDirection = function(){
  switch (this.direction) {
   case 'up':
      this.arrow = '▲';
      break
   case 'right':
      this.arrow = '►';
      break
   case 'bottom':
      this.arrow = '▼';
      break
   case 'left':
      this.arrow = '◄';
      break         
   default:
      console.log('error arrow direction');
      break
  }
}

Tank.prototype.checkBorderCollision = function(){
  switch (this.direction) {
   case 'up':
      this.y_coord -= 10;
      if(this.y_coord <= 0) this.y_coord = 0; 
      break
   case 'right':
      this.x_coord += 10;
      if(this.x_coord >= 480) this.x_coord = 480;
      break
   case 'bottom':
      this.y_coord += 10;
      if(this.y_coord >= 480) this.y_coord = 480;
      break
   case 'left':
      this.x_coord -= 10;
      if(this.x_coord <= 0) this.x_coord = 0;
      break         
   default:
      console.log('error direction definition');
      break
  }
}

Tank.prototype.checkChangeDirection = function(){
  if(helper.randomIntFromZero(100) > 75){
    this.direction = this.DIRECTION[helper.randomIntFromZero(4)];
  }
}

Tank.prototype.Offset = function(){
  $('#' + this.id).css({
    left: this.x_coord + 'px',
    top: this.y_coord + 'px'
  }).html(this.arrow);
}

Tank.prototype.Move = function(){
  this.checkChangeDirection();
  this.checkBorderCollision();
  this.checkArrowDirection();
  this.Offset();
}


function Helper(){
    this.randomIntFromInterval = function(minInclusive, maxExclusive){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxExclusive - minInclusive + 1)) + minInclusive;
    };

    this.randomIntFromZero = function(maxExclusive){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxExclusive));
    };  
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    var board = new Board(500, 500, 'orange'),
            tanks = [];

    helper = new Helper();          

    var i = 0;
    while (i < 6) {
      tanks[i] = new Tank(i);
      i++;
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 6) {
          tanks[i].Move();
          i++;
        }       
    }, 500);
});
```

but constructor Tank is not worked. console displays follow error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DIRECTION is not defined

i try use follow definition:

```
Tank.prototype.DIRECTION = function(){
  return ['up', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];
}
```

but it also not worked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with ES6. Or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you declare `DIRECTION` inside of constructor function, so it's not visible outside of constructor.

Move declaration `DIRECTION = ['up', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];` on the top of file, outside of any function, and it will work.

This code is the problem

```
Tank.prototype.Create = function(){
  self.direction = DIRECTION[helper.randomIntFromZero(4)];
```

Or, as mentioned in comments, if you want to store `DIRECTIONS` as object property, you should use `this.DIRECTIONS`, or `Tank.DIRECTIONS` if it's static field.

Comment: Or make it `Tank.prototype.DIRECTION` so you don't pollute the global namespace

Comment: Then use `this.DIRECTION` in the other function.

Comment: Same applies to `self`, only that hides `window.self` so you'd really be setting `window.self.direction` instead of `Tank.self.direction`

Comment: @linoleum, thanks. but your variant does not worked http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJddwq?editors=001

Comment: @stackow101 you use `self` in all the methods, but you don't declare it. Remember that `self` is not a keyword, it's just a variable, and you should declare it on the top of each method, or just use a plain `this`. Now there's no errors in console [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJdBYO?editors=001](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJdBYO?editors=001)